# Notepad++ Shortcut for Find All in All Opened Documents

Tags: search, plugins, macros, notepad++

How can I create a Notepad++ shortcut that launches **Find All in All Opened Documents** giving the selected text as a parameter?

In other words, after a text is selected, the shortcut should perform <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>, then open the **Search Result Window** for the selected text.

I tried to create a macro but it passes as parameter the specific text used to record the macro -> useless.

Comment: Don't post twice please: http://superuser.com/questions/809147/notepad-shortcut-for-find-all-in-all-opened-documents

Answer (score 4):

I think currently there is no way to create a shortcut for "find all" in notepad++.

But here is another way you can try:

Download and install AUTOHOTKEY, copy follow code into a .ahk file

```
F2::
Send ^f
Send !o
```

Execute it, then you can use "F2" to operate find all in opened document.

1. you can replace "F2" to any other key you prefer.
2. ^f mean Ctrl+f
3. !o mean Alt+o

Answer (score 1):

Press Ctrl + F, and then click "Find All in All Opened Documents"

Alternatively,Press Ctrl + F then you can press Alt + O (as the 'O' is underlined).

Answer (score 0):

Find All in current and open document with Notepad++

```
F2::
IfWinExist, AHK_CLASS Notepad++
    WinActivate, ahk_exe notepad++.exe
    Send ^f
    CoordMode, Mouse, Screen
    MouseMove, A_ScreenWidth/2, A_ScreenHeight/2
    sleep 50
    Click
    Send {Tab}{Tab}{Tab}{Tab}{Tab}{Tab}{Tab}{Tab}{Tab}{Enter}
return

+F2::
IfWinExist, AHK_CLASS Notepad++
    WinActivate, ahk_exe notepad++.exe
    Send ^f
    CoordMode, Mouse, Screen
    MouseMove, A_ScreenWidth/2, A_ScreenHeight/2
    sleep 50
    Click
    Send {Tab}{Tab}{Tab}{Tab}{Tab}{Tab}{Tab}{Tab}{Tab}{Tab}{Enter}
return
```

Use can use `alt+o` or `alt+d` as below in place for tabs, but i went with Tabs.

```
;Send !o
;Send !o
```

Answer (score -3):

try

Ctrl-Shift-F    Find in Files

best regards :-)

Comment: sorry but this is not answering the question ctrl-shift-f opens the find in files window. what I am looking for is a shortcut to perform ctrl-f alt-o, meaning that it should open the search results window with the findings for the selected text. thanks ...